# Getting data from children classes: Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm new here, so I apologize in advance if I do not follow standard etiquette on accident.

I'm wondering how to get data from a child class, using ArrayLists.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyProgrammingLab {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Test> testArray = new ArrayList<>();

        testArray.add(new Test("First"));
        testArray.add(new SubTest("Last"));

        System.out.println(testArray.get(0).getFirstName());
        System.out.println(testArray.get(1).getLastName());
    }
}

public class Test {
    private String firstName;

    public Test(){
    }

    public Test(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
}

public class SubTest extends Test{
    private String lastName;

    public SubTest(){
        super();
    }

    public SubTest(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

The line in my main "System.out.println(test.Array.get(1).getLastName());" is throwing errors at me, and I can't figure out why?

In my main program, I'll be using an ArrayList of size greater than 1.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advise being *very cautious* about using the solution I'm about to propose, but:

```
System.out.println(((SubTest) testArray.get(1)).getLastName());
```

However, only do this if you are *sure* that the element at position 1 is a SubTest, otherwise you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

If you're not sure, you should probably check.

```
Test whatIGot = testArray.get(1);
if(whatIGot instanceof SubTest) {
   SubTest whatIActuallyGot = (SubTest)whatIGot;
   System.out.println(whatIActuallyGot.getLastName());
}
```

Generally, you should avoid depending on properties of subclasses when you have a variable of a super class type. Doing so is a code smell and might be caused by bad design.

The proper solution would involve asking yourself these two questions:

- Are you absolutely sure `getLastName` belongs in `SubTest` and not in `Test`? If `getLastName()` was in `Test`, that'd solve the problem completely.
- Do you really need to access `getLastName` from a `testArray` element?

If `getLastName()` *does* belong in `Test`(all instances of `Test` have *some* last name), but you have no good default value for it, then consider making `Test` an abstract class with an abstract method `getLastName`. Be aware that this would make `new Test()` stop working.

Comment: Hence why I wouldn't advise this. Based on the type of question and code presented, the op is likely learning to program/Java. Suggesting such a way of solving the issue may lead to someone who "just wants to get it to work" to develop bad habits without understanding their misunderstanding.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions Added some advice. I believe this should cover the important parts. Anything more specific than this is impossible without knowing exactly what he/she wants to do exactly.

Comment: Thank you all for the advice. I can see why Casting is bad practice, however it seems my TA was wanting this in my situation, because we had just gone over instanceof. I will definitely keep in mind that this can get you into trouble when dealing with more complex structures.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is declared as `Arraylist<Test>`. This means that it is flexible: you can put any instance of `Test` (including instances of subclasses) in it.

With this flexibility comes a limitation: later on, when you get an element out again, all you can tell about the element is that it is an instance of `Test` - as you've discovered, you cannot tell without specific type checks whether the entry was a `Test` or a `SubTest`. (Consider how you would even write the `get` method on `ArrayList` if the list had to return the exact type of the entry - the return type of the method would change depending on the index passed in!)

If you need this flexibility (and your sample code suggests that you do, as you're also storing instances of `Test` alongside `SubTest`), your simplest option is to check the type and cast:

```
Test secondEntry = testArray.get(1);
if (secondEntry instanceof SubTest) {
    System.out.println(((SubTest) secondEntry).getLastName());
}
```

Although as others have pointed out, this somewhat defeats the point of using generics.

Other alternatives include:

- to move your `getLastName` method up to the parent class and then override it in the child class (if it makes sense for the parent class to have this method);
- to implement a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with type-based dispatch.

This would look something like:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyProgrammingLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Test> testArray = new ArrayList<Test>();

        testArray.add(new Test("First"));
        testArray.add(new SubTest("Last"));

        for (Test aTest : testArray) {
            emit(aTest);
        }

    }

    public static void emit(Test aTest) {
        if (aTest instanceof SubTest) {
            System.out.println(((SubTest) aTest).getLastName());
        } else {
            System.out.println(aTest.getFirstName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the most complete answer, though "strategy pattern with type based dispatch" may be overwhelming for a beginner without a simple code example (which is what you have the skeleton of anyway, just show the whole method and call for it to make sense).

Answer (score 0):

`testArray.get(1)` is returning type `Test`, not `SubTest`.  If you're absolutely sure it's a `SubTest` (you can do `instanceof` to check), then you can use

```
System.out.println(((SubTest) testArray.get(1)).getLastName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared it like this:

```
ArrayList<Test> testArray;
```

Java only knows that the `ArrayList` contains `Test` objects. Therefore, it **does not know** about any methods in the child class, **even if the object has that method**.

If you add this:

```
public String getLastName(){
    return ""; // do nothing
}
```

To your `Test` class, it will compile and work as you expect, because **now** `Test` objects have the `getLastName()` method.

Other solutions suggest casting, but I **strongly recommend against casting** here because that defeats the purpose of using generics. You don't want to be in situations where you cast and then handle `ClassCastException`s. The point of generics is to elegantly handle situations exactly like yours.

Comment: Yes, that will work...but advising to make all Animal bark() or breatheWithAir() is a hack at best. You should explain the trade-offs of this approach.

Comment: Well said. Using Generics is best done when some type of Strategy is implemented, such that the same method that is available on all objects is called, regardless of the type.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions: feel free to upvote if you like my answer so much :)

Comment: I like your explanation against casting, but hate the idea of bubbling methods up without explicit reasoning to get around compiler errors too. :)

Answer (score 0):

It may help to review the [Java Inheritence tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

When you declare an ArrayList, you are explicitly saying that you expect a list of things that are *exactly* `Test`. You can use Generics to include Test and anything that extends it, which is what `ArrayList<? extends Test>` does.

While this may solve your exact issue, you should know that it is poor design to [extend concrete classes](http://billharlan.com/pub/papers/Avoid_extending_classes.html) and you should use intermediary instance variables (e.g. `Test test1 = testArray.get(0)`) to avoid violating the [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Originally I had a separate ArrayList full of SubTests to deal with this. I had points taken off of my project with the explanation from my TA being "One ArrayList should be enough to handle everything except sort. Use instanceof" (sort is irrelevant for our discussion).

Comment: The TA is technically correct, if you use generics. If you haven't been taught generics yet, or the proper use of the instanceof operator, you should be able to argue those points back.

Comment: I'll talk to him tomorrow in my lab, maybe he'll be reasonable. I'm really impressed with how fast a solution was found. Thanks again